# showing blurry images in main page in futured posts in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogs

On the main page it's showing blurry image in futured posts.

website link:- iguidu.blogspot.com

I tried different methods but it is not working. can anyone?

related script:-

Answer (score 2):

Original image is only 72px and you're rendering into a large box, You're basically using thumbnails in the place of featured image, this is the reason it's blurry. try using larger images, ideally to the expected rending size, in your case 490 x 305px

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this seens to occur because of the images size. If you open each image in a new tab you will see that teir original size are 72x72 although the display size (the size that us, clients, are seeing) is 490x305.

How to correct this ? The ideal is to get a bigger image, and also an optimized one. The most optimezed format for web is .webp. Check on [THIS](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) link what is this.

Another important thing when comes to resize image is to keep the aspect ratio, but I don't think you are experiencing any issue with that, although I will let a [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) talking about it.